# sqlite add column if not exist with just sql

Tags: sqlite

out of curiosity is it possible to write an alter table add col statment with just sql. Since the statement is going into a script and I can't really do any sort of checks with C++.

So pretty much I am wondering if its possible to do something in the line of

Alter table "test" add "test_col" if 0 < ( select count("test_col") from "test");
or with combination of other sql statements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in SQLite.

You have to check this in your application, or just execute the script and ignore the error.